# How To Setup Multiple Conditionals Within React JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to do something similar to `if elseif else` statement in React.

Here is what I have currently, with just simple `true` or `false` conditional, and works fine

```
{isAdmin()  ? (
  <>
    <a href="/profile">admin</a>  
    <div class='container'></div>
  </>         
) : (
  <>
    <a href="/profile">user</a>
    <div class='container'></div>
  </>
)}
```

but now I want to have multiple conditionals. Tried this below

`isAdminTwo()` and `isAdminThree()` are children of `isAdmin()`, which means that they all must meet `isAdmin()` condition first

```
{isAdmin()  ? (
  <>
  <a href="/profile">admin</a>  
  <div class='container'></div>
  </>         
) : (
  <>
  {isAdminTwo()  ? (
  <>
    <a href="/profile">admin2</a>  
    <div class='container'></div>
  </>         
) : (
  <>
  {isAdminThree()  ? (
  <>
    <a href="/profile">admin3</a>  
    <div class='container'></div>
  </>         
) : (
  <>
    <a href="/profile">user</a>
    <div class='container'></div>
  </>
)}
```

but getting errors

```
TypeError: ge(...) is not a function
```

What is a proper way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried using if else to render

Comment: I haven't as i have only done it this way. I looked around and did not helpful enough sources to help with if else. Am open to whichever works for what i want

Comment: I would suggest that you use if else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start off, you should not be doing that. Rather go for a syntax like

```
    if (isAdmin())
        return (
            <>
                <a href="/profile">admin</a>
                <div class="container"></div>
            </>
        );
    if (isAdmin() && isAdminTwo())
        return (
            <>
                <a href="/profile">admin2</a>
                <div class="container"></div>
            </>
        );
    if (isAdmin() && isAdminThree())
        return (
            <>
                <a href="/profile">admin3</a>
                <div class="container"></div>
            </>
        );
    return (
        <>
            <a href="/profile">user</a>
            <div class="container"></div>
        </>
    );
```

Or if you want to use it within other component that is always the same:

```
    let contents = (
        <>
            <a href="/profile">user</a>
            <div class="container"></div>
        </>
    );
    if (isAdmin())
        contents = (
            <>
                <a href="/profile">admin</a>
                <div class="container"></div>
            </>
        );
    if (isAdmin() && isAdminTwo())
        contents = (
            <>
                <a href="/profile">admin2</a>
                <div class="container"></div>
            </>
        );
    if (isAdmin() && isAdminThree())
        contents = (
            <>
                <a href="/profile">admin3</a>
                <div class="container"></div>
            </>
        );

    return <SameWrapper>{contents}</SameWrapper>;
```

But if you wanted to do it with ternary operators (which would be most probably not readable for other people and you in the future), kepp in mind correct syntax of ternary operator:

```
truthCheck ? ifTrue : ifFalse
```

So your example should go along the way

```
    isAdmin() ? (
        isAdminTwo() ? (
            <>
                <a href="/profile">admin2</a>
                <div class="container"></div>
            </>
        ) : isAdminThree() ? (
            <>
                <a href="/profile">admin3</a>
                <div class="container"></div>
            </>
        ) : (
            <>
                <a href="/profile">admin</a>
                <div class="container"></div>
            </>
        )
    ) : (
        <>
            <a href="/profile">user</a>
            <div class="container"></div>
        </>
    );
```

Where your `truthCheck` is there, and if `true` display a component, but if `false` perform next check. In your code these fragments are causing bugs:

```
<> // <--- these are not needed
{isAdminTwo()  ? (
<> // <--- these are not needed
// same for below
```

Comment: mind using the simple example i have rather than using components like `return <Admin />` can you update with the way i have it please...thanks

Comment: okay give me a sec

Comment: by the way the first conditional is a parent, and the others wrap under it, which was why i had it the way i did. `isAdminTwo()` and `isAdminTwo()` are child of `isAdmin()` i updated question also with this info

Comment: Did you read the update to the question? `isAdminTwo()` and `isAdminThree()` are children of `isAdmin()` which means that they all must meet isAdmin() condition first

Comment: Yes I did, these checks will not be run unless `isAdmin()` is true

Comment: `isAdminTwo()` and `isAdminThree()` are not related, they are both children of `isAdmin()`. and are not children of each other

Comment: Also i prefer not to use the `const` prefer your previous answer that use what i have without `const` or `let`

Comment: Then modify my answer yourself so it is done the way you like it. I have answered you, but codeflow isn't the subject of the question.

Comment: will accept as answer, just prefer to modify the code i have in the question without using `const` or `let` or anything else. Just remember the children thing.

Comment: issue is trying to still figure out the answer, i know you tried but your answer is not straight to the point of what am after...best to keep answers simple

Comment: I have removed all the variables from the answer, keep in mind it is probably a bad practice since you are invoking `isAdmin()` three times if client is adminThree instead of once.

Comment: so means i have to check isAdmin() that many times? No way to nest the other isAdminTwo and isAdminThree under isAdmin? So i only check isAdmin once and if true then check isAdminTwo or isAdminThree?

Comment: Yeah I didn't thought of that, will modify my answer but only the last segment since this one is the only one you care about

Comment: I have modified my answer. Remember also to change `class="container"` to `className="container"` since this is the working thing in React.

Comment: thanks...liked the answer that is closest to what i have...appreciate the help..tested and looks good